# how to change file access in windows in python

Tags: python, windows, pywin32, dacl

My program processes a perticular file , if some condition is satisfied , then it has to block the access (READ n WRITE ) to that file , for all user even for the admin.

Later , when another function is called , it  has to change the access control settings back to normal.

i have tried the following code

```
import os, sys
import win32api
import win32security
import ntsecuritycon as con

FILENAME = "temp.txt"
os.remove (FILENAME)

def show_cacls (filename):
print
print
for line in os.popen ("cacls %s" % filename).read ().splitlines ():
print line

#
# Find the SIDs for Everyone, the Admin group and the current user
#
everyone, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountName ("", "Everyone")
admins, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountName ("", "Administrators")
user, domain, type = win32security.LookupAccountName ("", win32api.GetUserName ())

#
# Touch the file and use CACLS to show its default permissions
# (which will probably be: Admins->Full; Owner->Full; Everyone->Read)
#    
open (FILENAME, "w").close ()
show_cacls (FILENAME)

#
# Find the DACL part of the Security Descriptor for the file
#
sd = win32security.GetFileSecurity (FILENAME, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION)

#
# Create a blank DACL and add the three ACEs we want
# We will completely replace the original DACL with
# this. Obviously you might want to alter the original
# instead.
#
dacl = win32security.ACL ()
dacl.AddAccessAllowedAce (win32security.ACL_REVISION, con.FILE_GENERIC_ALL, everyone)
dacl.AddAccessAllowedAce (win32security.ACL_REVISION, con.FILE_GENERIC_ALL , user)
dacl.AddAccessAllowedAce (win32security.ACL_REVISION, con.FILE_GENERIC_ALL, admins)

#
# Put our new DACL into the Security Descriptor,
# update the file with the updated SD, and use
# CACLS to show what's what.
#
sd.SetSecurityDescriptorDacl (1, dacl, 0)
win32security.SetFileSecurity (FILENAME, win32security.DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION, sd)
show_cacls (FILENAME)
```

IT Works fine to block write access. But I can't block read access . Also i don't know any method to restore the previous access settings , because if i block the read access for admin , it will not word.

please tell me how to implement the required functions.

Comment: Are you trying to block access through security?  Wouldn't it be easier to have your process lock the file?  http://docs.activestate.com/activepython/2.4/pywin32/win32file__LockFileEx_meth.html

Comment: Did you ever find a way to block access to a file?